# get resource from ASP.NET App_GlobalResources in separate DLL Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, get

I have a solution with one web project and one class library. In web project I have App_GlobalResources folder with resource file. In code used in web project I can access resourcel like this:
string r = Resources.res.ResourceString123;

How to get this resource string from class library?

Comment: First you make sure that the global resource file is available in public 
https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/making-global-resources-public/

Comment: then in your view "using YourProjectName.App_GlobalResources;" and then "Content.msg", I have Content.resx file in my global resource with key of "msg"

Answer (score 1):

I also use a separate assembly for my web project and class libraries. I required access to my App_GlobalResources in the web project for my ModelBinders. I access the resource is via this method (see: [A Beginner's Guide to ASP.NET Application Folders](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders#n)).

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject( string classKey , string resourceKey )
```

Once caveat is that you will need access to the HttpContext, which I have via the controllerContext in my ModelBinder.

My ModelBinder code reads as follows:

```
var errorMessage = controllerContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject( "DefaultModelBinder" , "PropertyValueRequired" ) as string;
```

The above allows me to have a consistent error message across ASP.NET's default error messages and my ModelBinders, even though I have them in separate assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 2.0, you will need to add the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to the assembly & set it to the namespace which needs to access the file:

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Another options could be to create a class in the class library which can return the strings you need...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If using visual studio 2008 you can set the access modifier on the [Resource designer](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/12/01/share-resources-between-projects.aspx) to `public` in the class library.